# I cannot launch p2os_driver

Tags: ros, p2os-driver, p2os, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have cloned p2os from this [site](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os) then I have executed `catkin_make`. When I `rosrun p2os_driver p2os_driver` the node looks working but after a while it looks crashing and the robot starts ringing. This is what I obtain when I run the node :

```
~/catkin_ws$ rosrun p2os_driver p2os_driver 
[ INFO] [1437702473.149237607]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
[ INFO] [1437702473.168836447]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyUSB0...
[ INFO] [1437702473.589839367]: SYNC0
[ INFO] [1437702473.791675807]: turning off NONBLOCK mode...
[ INFO] [1437702473.992170005]: SYNC1
[ INFO] [1437702474.392637407]: SYNC2
[ INFO] [1437702474.993597928]: Done.
Connected to Revast_3717, a Pioneer p3dx-sh
```

After that, I try to `roslaunch p2os_launch p2os_driver.launch` I get an error. This is what is happening:

```
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch p2os_launch p2os_driver.launch 
... logging to /home/robotics/.ros/log/1a8aae94-31a5-11e5-879a-1093e908a012/roslaunch-robotics-MacBookAir-29917.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://robotics-MacBookAir:43467/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    p2os_driver (p2os_driver/p2os_driver)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[p2os_driver-1]: started with pid [29935]
[ERROR] [1437702514.232441287]: P2OS::Setup():open():
[p2os_driver-1] process has died [pid 29935, exit code -11, cmd /home/robotics/catkin_ws/devel/lib/p2os_driver/p2os_driver __name:=p2os_driver __log:=/home/robotics/.ros/log/1a8aae94-31a5-11e5-879a-1093e908a012/p2os_driver-1.log].
log file: /home/robotics/.ros/log/1a8aae94-31a5-11e5-879a-1093e908a012/p2os_driver-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Do you have an idea what could cause this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214460/i-cannot-launch-p2os_driver/) by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Using `<param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>` instead of `<remap from="port" to="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>` in your roslaunch file.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [yz](https://answers.ros.org/users/9021/yz/) with karma: 26 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1